# Slack :: How to configure Slack to request a GET call and pass along option arguments via query string param

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, slack, slack-api

I am working on a POC to explore Azure Function integration via webhook which requests a GET call to custom code, which makes a call to Google Directions API to return JSON data to Slack custom trigger.

The custom code is finished and working verified via Postman. Somehow either Slack does not have the ability to do something like:

`/directions origin=[ORIGIN_ADDRESS], destination=[DESTINATION_ADDRESS]`

In which data is returned... has anyone successfully solved this in the past? Is this even possible?

Comment: @ErikKalkoken which part isn't possible? Per the API docs, you can create a custom slash command that performs a GET or POST on a given url.  The addresses would be sent to the url as plain text so they'd have to be parsed on the server.  I haven't built a slack app but I don't see why this wouldn't be possible https://api.slack.com/slash-commands

Comment: @GarrettMcCullough I agree, I see two options - If Slack is able to build a query string on a GET or a payload via a POST ... either would work, but there are not documents on this. If the slash command isn’t able to trigger a POST but only a GET via a incoming webhook then there should be the ability to create a query string ... unless a bother server is needed, I am just not sure.

Comment: @GarrettMcCullough This question is a bit vague. But as I understand him he wants to trigger that command via a GET or POST request. A slash command on the other hand is meant to be triggered from within the Slack platform, not by a webhook. Although, there is an undocumented API call, that allows triggering a slash command with [chat.command](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/chat.command.md) For that you need a legacy token though.

Comment: @jdave - GarrettMcCullough is right. Slash commands in Slack send a POST with multipart/form-data as the payload. Your example would send the entire text after /directions as the "text" field, which you could then split and process accordingly. The Slack documentation GarrettMcCullough is really good, showing examples of the data sent. You just have to build your function to match (it's pretty straightforward). The catch is that you may need to respond initially with an ephemeral message, then use the response_url provided by Slack to send back the full message, once processing is complete.